# WPF Bindings of a Custom User Control with a ComboBox containing a DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, listview, combobox, binding, user-controls

I am trying to create a Custom User Control with a ListView in it that contains a Data Template looking like this:

```
        <ComboBox  ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource, ElementName=root}" 
               SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=root, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">                        
                    
                    <!-- This is what I tried:
                    
Working but not what I want                 <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}"/>    
Returns the List only the word "FallBack"   <TextBox Text="{Binding ItemText, ElementName=root}" />
Returns the LIst empty                      <TextBox Text="{Binding ItemText}" />
                    -->
                    
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

In the code behind I have created the necessary dependency properties for this case (so I assume) the only relevant one is regarding the Item Text and it looks like that:

```
    #region ItemText

    public string ItemText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ItemTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemTextProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ItemText.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ItemText", typeof(string), typeof(CardComboBox), new PropertyMetadata("FallBack"));

    #endregion
```

What I would like to do is to add the User Control like that

```
  <local:CardComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson}" ItemText="{Binding Name}" IsEnabled="True" />
```

Option one:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Name}"/>
```

works fine because the PropertyName of the Class Person is Name, but I obviously do not want to HardCode it. I want to bind it to whichever property I like.

Option 2:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ItemText, ElementName=root}" />
```

Gives me the list of 7 items (as per list) but just displays the word "Fallback" because of the DependencyPropertyMetadata.

Option 3:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ItemText}" />
```

Gives me the list but with no text at all.

I also tried to work with relativeSource but only with similar results.

```
   #region Person

    Person _selectedPerson;
    public Person SelectedPerson
    {
        get => _selectedPerson;
        set
        {
            if (value != _selectedPerson)
            {
                _selectedPerson = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedPerson");

            }
        }
    }


    ObservableCollection<Person> _persons;
    public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons
    {
        get => _persons;
        set
        {
            if (value != _persons)
            {
                _persons = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Persons");

            }
        }
    }

    public void populatePersons()
    {
        Persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>();  
        Persons.Add(new Person("Carl"));
        Persons.Add(new Person("Max"));
        Persons.Add(new Person("May"));
        Persons.Add(new Person("Jen"));
        Persons.Add(new Person("Charly"));
        Persons.Add(new Person("Nora"));
        Persons.Add(new Person("Yvonne"));
    }

    #endregion
```

I have added the List I am binding to. The Method Populate Persons is called in the constructor of the ViewModel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest solution working so far is to expose the ItemContentTemplate Dependency Property and then to bind it to a static resource (e.g. from App.xaml)

The XAML of the UserControl looks like this:

```
     <StackPanel Style="{StaticResource CardStackPanel}" Orientation="{Binding Orientation, ElementName=root}" >
        <Label  x:Name="Label" Content="{Binding TitleText, ElementName=root}"/>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource ="{Binding ItemsSource,           RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" 
                  ItemTemplate="{Binding ItemContentTemplate,   RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" 
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem,          RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Mode=TwoWay}" />
 </StackPanel>
```

the Code Behind for the ComboBox Part:

```
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(CardComboBox));
    public IEnumerable ItemsSource
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }


    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItem", typeof(object), typeof(CardComboBox));
    public object SelectedItem
    {
        get { return GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }
    }

    public DataTemplate ItemContentTemplate
    {
        get { return (DataTemplate)GetValue(ItemContentTemplateProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemContentTemplateProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemContentTemplateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ItemContentTemplate", typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(CardComboBox));
```

The Static Ressource in App.xaml (example):

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="FirstNamesTemplate">
        <Label Content="{Binding FirstName}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
```

The Implementation of a ComboBoxCard looks now like this:

```
<local:CardComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding PersonModels}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPersonModel, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemContentTemplate="{StaticResource FirstNamesTemplate}" TitleText="With StaticResource" IsEnabled="False"/>
```

This pattern allows to implement ComboBoxes or ListViews in Custom UserControls .

Comment: Why define `ItemsSource` and `ItemContentTemplate` properties instead of inheriting from `ItemsSource`?

Answer (score 0):

`<TextBox Text="{Binding ItemText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:CardComboBox}}" />` will bind the `TextBox` to the current value of the `ItemText` dependency property of the parent `CardComboBox` if that's what you want.

However, if you want to display the value of the `Name` property of each `Person` byt you also want to be able specify the name of the property of `Person` to bind to using your `ItemText` property, you will have to create the binding programmtically.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately that gives me a similar result as option 2, a list of the word "FallBack"

Comment: A list? Please explain what you mean. I guess you didn't set the value of `ItemText` then? What if you set it to a constant value like   `<local:CardComboBox ... ItemText="Test" />`?

Comment: With List I mean the List when you open the ComboBox... the 7 Items corresponding to the 7 Objects in ObservableCollection<Person> Persons which is bound to the ItemsSource.  
When I do as you suggest I get 7times Test

Comment: Did you read my question? What's the value of the property that you bind to? Where and how do you set it?

Comment: My Apologies, The result from your request was 7 times Test. The Value of the properties are 7 different names (Carl, Mark, Mariola, Yen, etc.)

Comment: Obviously the value is set to "Test" then!? So the binding I suggested clearly works. You don't seem to know how to set a dependency property though.

Comment: The List of Persons is in the ViewModel. If I use a ComboBox in the View and map it normally everything works fine. Just not if I want to use my UserControl.

Comment: You're binding to a `string` property. What list are you talking about? There is no one present in your (rather confusing and poor) example.

Comment: I think you are right the Dependency Property of the TextBox is probably the source of the issue. But I do not understand what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You have created a `string` property and want to see the current of this value in the `TextBox` in the `ItemTemplate`? What's the problem and how is this related to some list of values?

Comment: In the ComboBox of CardComboBox I want to see the "List" or DropDown of Names from the 'ObservableCollection<Person> Persons' . It shows 7 Items in the DropDown so the binding seems fine, but it will not display the names.

Comment: I think I understand you want now. You want to display the value of the `Name` property of each `Person` and you want to specify the *name* of the property of `Person` to bind to using your `ItemText` property, right? This doesn't work in XAML. You will have to create this binding programmtically.

Comment: That's right! I hope to create UserControls with ComboBoxes or ListViews which already have already their ItemTemplates setup and just require "wiring up".

Comment: Then binding to a dependency property won't solve your issue I am afraid.

Comment: @CKnodyvara You should not worry about the `DataTemplate`. `DataTemplate` is not a concern for the author of a generic control. Just provide the layout and data hosts. Let the user of the control define the `DataTemplate` for his data. This is how it is done. Otherwise, you have no chance to create a generic control (which sounds like goal of yours). You can consider to add an `ItemTemplate` dependency property to your `UserControl` and bind it to the `ComboBox`.

Comment: @CKnodyvara If the `ComboBox` is your only or main content or the only `ItemsControl` in the template, you should definitely extend the `ComboBox` class instead of `UserControl`. This way you have all the required properties like `ItemsSource` and `ItemTemplate`. Simply override the default template to give it your specialized layout. Override the virtual methods to change or extend the default behavior. It looks like `CardComboBox` should really be a custom `ComboBox`.

Comment: @BionicCode You are right. Exposing the ItemTemplate DP in the code-behind seems to be the right (so far only) approach. I then place the required DataTemplate in the App.xaml and bind them together. It's a bit of a workaround but still allows me to centralise the code for my CardComboBox. The added benefit is that I do not need to create a CardComboBox kind of control each time for each DataTemplate.